# React Navigation - Drawer inside Stack go back

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Taking this example for the official documentation :

```
function Root() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Root"
          component={Root}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

They just explain here how to navigate to the Profile screen from the Feed screen like this :

```
navigation.navigate('Root', { screen: 'Profile' });
```

I would to know how can I navigate to the Feed screen from the Profile screen;